# Git is showing me two different messages

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting the message in my terminal after running `git status` that my branch `feature/my-branch` is ahead of `origin/feature/my-branch` by 13 commits. But on bitbucket the pull request is saying that  my branch `feature/my-branch` is behind 12 commits from "master". Can anyone explain to me what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: It's not a problem so there is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting the message in my terminal after running git status that my branch feature/my-branch is ahead of origin/feature/my-branch by 13 commits.

You have made 13 commits since originally checking out `feature/mybranch` locally.

> But on bitbucket the pull request is saying that my branch feature/my-branch is behind 12 commits from "master"

The `master` branch has been modified since `feature/my-branch` was originally created.

You should probably (a) ensure your local repository is up-to-date with respect to the remote (`git remote update`) and then (b) rebase `feature/my-branch` on the upstream `master` branch (that could be `git rebase origin/master`, assuming the target branch of your pull request is `master` in the `origin` remote.